# Using subplot_kw in matplotlib to create a polar projection in subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a polar projection using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()` but I get the error `projection is not defined` when I try to pass a dictionary to `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()`

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, subplot_kw={projection:'polar'})
```

However `plt.subplot(1,1,1, projection='polar')` works as expected. The documentation for [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) says that the dictionary in `subplot_kw` will be passed to [`add.subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) which takes projection as a optional parameter so I'm not sure what my mistake is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs that you linked don't actually show `subplot_kw` being used in that way. What they show is calling `dict()`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
```

If you print the output of `subplot_kw=dict(polar=True)`, you get:

```
{'polar': True}
```

Notice that `polar` has now become a string. `subplot_kw={projection:'polar'})` does not define `projection` as a string, it's just a variable name that Python now has to look up (and it won't find it in this case, but it may find something else in other cases).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm a fool. I added  ' ' around projection so `subplot_kw = {'projection' : 'polar'}` and now it works.

Comment: @Bprodz tbh, I'm not sure the docs used the best approach to representing this example.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly to clarify which was the mistake in the original post and to complete the previous answer.

Following the `plt.subplots()` documentation you cited, the argument `subplot_kw` is expected to be dictionary. There are two equivalent ways of doing this.

**option 1:**
Use the function `dict()` to create the dictionary to pass:
`subplot_kw = dict(projection = 'polar')`

**oprtion 2:**
Pass directly the dictionary in with the correct key-value structure
`subplot_kw = {'projection' : 'polar'}`

Notice that in the first option the word `projection` does not need to be a string and you can use and equal `=` sign. The function `dict` will do the job of formating the dictionary from its arguments. You can verify this simply by doing:

`>>>dict(projection = 'polar')`
`Output: {'projection' : 'polar'}`